# Specific Datatype for this situation?

Tags: java, arrays, types

I want to pull data from a database. Name, Age, Sex, Location.(maybe more fields)

I want to hold the data in an object similar to how I would expect it to look in a JSON object.

Like:

```
 myData{
        row1[name:beavis, age:48, sex:male, location:Joburg]
        row2[name:quintus, age:43, sex:, location:Helsinki]   
        ...up to say 500 rows
    }
```

So i'd like to be able to do `tempName = row(i).name` and so on in java.

Any suggestions.

Comment: that doesn't look like valid json to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Defines a Person datatype
public class Person {
  // fields
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private String location;

  // gets the value of a field
  public String getName() {
     return name;
  }

  // sets the value of a field
  public void setName(aName) {
     this.name = aName;
  }

}
```

What I did here was define a Person type with a number of fields. Also I give here an example of a setter and getter for the name field. You can put them in an array or collection. For example:

```
Person people[] = new Person[2];
people[0] = new Person();
people[0].setName("Alice");
```

You can also dispense with the setters and getters by making the fields public, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Navi, I'll upvote your answer when you provide some notes on what you did here and also how to call into this code.  It is the right approach - just needs to be touched up.

Comment: How would this Person class be used?

Answer (score 0):

A straight translation of that data structure would be along the lines of

```
List<Map<String, Object>> myData
```

so you'd be able to call

```
tempName = (String) myData.get(i).get("name");
```

Like the JSON array, this doesn't enforce typing (which you'll have to deal with explicitly in Java) and doesn't limit the fields to only those from the database.

If all the database values are strings, things get cleaner as no casts are necessary.

```
List<Map<String, String>> myData
tempName = myData.get(i).get("name");
```